# .tabViewStyle change on .onAppear/.onDisappear freezing the application

Tags: swift, swiftui

I want to be able to hide the tab bar in iOS 15 in some screens and, the way I found to do it, while allowing that bottom area to be able to be interacted with, was by adding a view modifier that takes a `shouldHide` boolean that comes by an environment variable and change the tab view style.

ContentView

```
    TabView(selection: $tabBarData.itemSelected) {
        NavigationStackView(navigationStack: router.navigationStack) {
            router.rootView(loggedUser)
        }
        .tag(1)

        ...
    }
    .hideTabBar(environment.isTabBarHidden)
```

ViewModifier

```
    struct HideTabBarViewModifier: ViewModifier {
        let shouldHideTabBar: Bool

        func body(content: Content) -> some View {
            if shouldHideTabBar {
                content
                    .tabViewStyle(.page(indexDisplayMode: .never))
            } else {
                content
                    .tabViewStyle(.automatic)
            }
        }
    }

    func hideTabBar(_ shouldHideTabBar: Bool) -> some View {
        modifier(HideTabBarViewModifier(shouldHideTabBar: shouldHideTabBar))
    }
```

Screen where I want to hide the tab bar

```
    VStack {}
        .onAppear {
            environment.isTabBarHidden = true
        }
        .onDisappear {
            environment.isTabBarHidden = false
        }
```

I have searched thoroughly to check if there was a strong retain cycle as I can see some view models and interactors (de)initing a million times whenever it freezes but without this code it never ever happened.

Is this code re-rendering every single view in the stack and therefore making this happen? Is there any other solution that could tackle this challenge that is hiding the tab bar in iOS 15? I really wish I could use `.toolbar(.hidden, for: .tabBar)` but unfortunately it is only available in iOS 16.